# Web page loads very slow

Tags: php, html, optimization

I have this webpage which loads very slow: https://www.mlh-shop.com/press/233

There are 185 small images in that slider. How can I optimize it in order to load faster?

Can I load only a few images, display the page, and then load the other ones in background?

Comment: This might help: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: This page makes 242 requests for 13MB.  You should not be surprised that it is slow.  +1 for lazyload.  That's a great start.

Comment: LazyLoad looks interesting. I'll give it a try.

Comment: This question should be on the web development stack exchange site: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: valid web pages load faster: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mlh-shop.com%2Fpress%2F233

Answer (score 3):

There are built-in limits in browsers as to the number of simultaneous connections PER DOMAIN allowed (modern browsers default to eight). One way to speed this up is to use a CDN - Content Delivery Network - which loads images from separate domains.

Another issue is how to make the page useable as fast as possible. For this, you use "Lazy loading" where only the minimum number of images are loaded with the page HTML, the rest are dynamically loaded using JavaScript. You send a list of images, then start fetching them after the page has finished loading.

This doesn't really "speed up" the loading times, but rather allows the page TO BE USED immediately while loading the images in the background.

You can combine these two techniques for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your site through Google Page Speed Analisys, here's what they suggest:

1. Images are resized in HTML or CSS. Serving scaled images could save
   3.4MiB (29% reduction).
2. Optimizing (compressing their file size) the images could reduce
   their size by 2.6MiB (22% reduction).
3. The cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for your resources...

For #3 you could simply use an .htaccess rule to set the expiration date on downloaded assets. Here is a strait forward guid on doing that: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/set-expires/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is to pre-process all of the images in the slider into one large static image.

Comment: While this is good for UI elements (CSS sprites) the size and number of images on THIS PAGE combined would lead to the page not being usable until the whole composite image is downloaded.

Comment: @Diodeus: Yes true, but I bet you that with very high JPEG compression it could be as small as 300KB. This would make the images rather blurry but just how good do they need to look? I loaded the page and those images are not worth 13MB.

Answer (score 0):

You should use lazy loading. Don't output all the img elements with PHP, instead create them later on the client side, using JavaScript. This has no real usability penalty in your case, as your slider already uses JavaScript and won't work anyway, if a user has JS disabled.